# Import Products into Store View 3 but Images missing off Site

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image, multistore

We have a created a CSV to import all products into Store View 3. with all the image columns,

```
image,image_label,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,small_image,small_image_label
```

the CSV contains other fields including SKU. The file imports fine into Store View 3. The images looks ok too.

However under the Default View - the images are uploaded but not selected? If I go into Store View 3, then the images are there and ticked.

As such, these images do not appear on the site.

How do I fix this on the CSV?

I have gone through the various posts on Stack and Google.

I hope someone is able to help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this: make a product and configure it **manually** the way you want.

Use the Magento built in export feature and export that product in particular.

There you will see the exact config you should use when importing in order to make the product just as the one you manually configured.

Comment: I shall try and get back to you.